# How to compare two dictionaries tuple values in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two dictionaries with one key and value as tuple (two values). I want to do the following:

- compare both dictionaries on the basis of key. If keys are matched, then their tuple should be compare.
- also if both dictionaries contain different key i.e. unmatched key, it should give an error.

It can be either linq expression or simple loops and check.

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict1= new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict2= new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
```

Comment: So... what error are you getting, what is happening, what did you try ?

Comment: i am familiar with comparing simple dictionary in c# with 1 key and 1 value. but for this case, i am unable to do so.

Comment: The `System.Tuple` family of types do not overload the `==` and `!=`. This is unfortunate. However, for both performance, and ergonomics, you should consider using the `System.ValueTuple` family of types which support `==` and `!=` and can be written concisely as `(string, string)`, i.e. `Dictionary<string, (string, string)>`

Comment: Just start with an *old school* `for`/`foreach` loop and a few `if` *statements*?

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly is your expected outcome? Are you checking if the dictionaries are equal (have the same keys and also the same tuples for the same keys)? Is ordering important between values in tuples?

Comment: @ M. Azyoksul exaclty that's my expected result. Yes although there are only two values in tuple but theyr are in order as i set them through database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to check if the dictionaries are equal or not, you can use the following code

```
// Checks if the dictionaries are equal
public static bool AreDictionriesEqual(Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict1, Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict2)
{
    // Check if the number of items are the same
    if (dict1.Count != dict2.Count)
        return false;

    // Get set of keys in both dictionaries
    var dict1Keys = dict1.Select(item => item.Key);
    var dict2Keys = dict2.Select(item => item.Key);

    // Check if the set of keys are the same
    if (!dict1Keys.All(key => dict2Keys.Contains(key)))
        return false;

    // Check if the strings in tuples are the same
    foreach(var item in dict1)
    {
        // Get first items
        var string1_Dict1 = item.Value.Item1;
        var string1_Dict2 = dict2[item.Key].Item1;

        // Check first items
        if (!string1_Dict1.Equals(string1_Dict2))
            return false;

        // Get second items
        var string2_Dict1 = item.Value.Item2;
        var string2_Dict2 = dict2[item.Key].Item2;

        // Check second items
        if (!string2_Dict1.Equals(string2_Dict2))
            return false;
    }

    // If we reach end, return true
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class DictionaryExtensions {
    public static bool IsEqualTo(this Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict1, Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict2) {
        if (!Enumerable.SequenceEqual(dict1.Keys.OrderBy(x => x), dict2.Keys.OrderBy(x => x))) {
            return false;
        }
            
        foreach(var kvp in dict1) {
            var corresponding = dict2[kvp.Key];
            
            if (kvp.Value.Item1 != corresponding.Item1 || kvp.Value.Item2 != corresponding.Item2) {
                return false;
            }
        }
            
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict1= new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict2= new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
        
        Console.WriteLine(dict1.IsEqualTo(dict2)); // True
        
        dict1["a"] = new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b");
        dict2["a"] = new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b");
        
        Console.WriteLine(dict1.IsEqualTo(dict2)); // True
        
        dict2["a"] = new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b2");
        
        Console.WriteLine(dict1.IsEqualTo(dict2)); // False

        dict2["a"] = new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b");
        dict2["b"] = new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b2");

        Console.WriteLine(dict1.IsEqualTo(dict2)); // False
```

**Update** Thanks to **Aluan Haddad** for pointing out the sorting issue.

Comment: Is it a nice approach but I don't believe there's any guarantee that the keys will be ordered. You likely need to sort them or use a set operation like `d1.Keys.Count != d2.Keys.Count || d1.Keys.Except(d2.Keys).Any()`